# AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'startswith'

Tags: django, python-2.7, tuples, django-settings

Completely new to coding, sorry for the simple questions. I'm getting this attribute error when running `python manage.py collectstatic`. I'm editing `settings.py`.  I have Django 1.5.1 and Python 2.7.5. Any help is appreciated and thanks in advance (again).

```
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/posixpath.py", line 61, in isabs
    return s.startswith('/')
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'startswith'
```

Now, of course I've never messed with `posixpath.py`.

here's the contents of `settings.py`(minus db info and such):

```
MEDIA_ROOT = "os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file___))", "static", "media"

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

STATIC_ROOT = "os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))", "static", "static-only"

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    "os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))", "static", "static",
)

STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
#    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.DefaultStorageFinder',
)

SECRET_KEY = 'xxxxxxxxx'

TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
#     'django.template.loaders.eggs.Loader',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'mvp_landing.urls'

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'mvp_landing.wsgi.application'

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__)), "static", "templates",
)

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.admindocs',
    'south',
    'join',   
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
)
```

Comment: In my case I had a copy/paste bug. My `STATIC_ROOT=` ended with a comma.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You do it wrong. You shouldn't turn your code in quotes. [Watch here how it should be](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/)

It should be like:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "static")
)
```

Also it belongs to your `MEDIA_ROOT` and `STATIC_ROOT` settings.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I did try this and it worked. I'm still very new. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

@chris

STATIC_ROOT and MEDIA_ROOTS are absolute paths and they cannot be tuples so no ","(commas) is allowed, 
So mention the absolute path as "/your/static/file/absolute/path"

Hope this will help :)

Answer (score 3):

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static_in_pro","static_root"),
```

Please Remove the comma at end of Static root

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static_in_pro","static_root")
```

Answer (score 2):

**Summary**

If you're new to Django (like I am) and run into this issue, I recommend looking over the book Two Scoops of Django's, in particular they have a GitHub template with a good app layout [here](https://github.com/twoscoops/django-twoscoops-project/tree/develop/project_name).  In particular, you want to look at:

1. Their '[base.py](https://github.com/twoscoops/django-twoscoops-project/blob/develop/project_name/project_name/settings/base.py)' file under settings, which has all of the configurations for 'STATIC_ROOT', 'MEDIA_ROOT', etc.
2. See how their settings matches their folder structure (see below)
   [image: twoscoopsrecommendsettings]

**Octotree (Optional)**

As a side note, if you use GitHub as source control, I highly recommend getting this Chrome extension called Octotree available [here](https://github.com/buunguyen/octotree).  This lets you view the folder layout of any GitHub repository.

[image: octotree extension]